# Remove Item From DataService Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I am trying to remove an item from my dataService, and update all components however I am having trouble, no matter what I try I am unable to remove the item from the dataService and have the body component update. What am I missing here? Do I need to change anything with the body components constructor? Thank you.

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<app-body></app-body>
```

footer.component.ts

```
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
nominations = [];
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.nominations$.subscribe(noms => this.nominations.push(noms));
    this.nominations.splice(0, 1);
  }
remove(indx: number){
    //remove movie from array in footer
    this.nominations.splice(indx, 1);
    //remove movie from dataService
    this.dataService.removeNomination(indx);
  }
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private nominations = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  nominations$ = this.nominations.asObservable();

  constructor() { 
    this.addNominations(this.nominations);
  }

  getNominations(){
    return this.nominations;
  }

  addNominations(nom: Object){
    this.nominations.next(nom);
  }

  removeNomination(index: number){
    delete this.nominations$[index];   
  }

}
```

body.component.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.nominations.subscribe(noms => this.nominations.push(noms));
    this.nominations.splice(0, 1);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need nominations$

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  public nominations = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

  constructor() { 
    
  }

  setNominations(nom: Object){
    this.nominations.next(nom);
  }
}
```

footer.component.ts

```
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
nominations = [];
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.nominations.subscribe(noms => this.nominations.push(noms));
  }
remove(indx: number){
    //remove movie from array in footer
    this.nominations.splice(indx, 1);
    //remove movie from dataService
    this.dataService.setNominations(this.nominations);
  }
```

then every where you subscribe to nominations get spliced nominations.

Comment: I tried this, however I am still having an issue with my body not receiving the updated list of nominations.

Comment: do you have different instances of dataService ?

Comment: there is an instance in my body component and in the footer component. they are created in the constructors.

Comment: my answer should work .can u create stackblitz demo ?